# Docker timeout port 53 - ISP to blame?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, firewall, docker

I'm running a Synology NAS with docker and used to have multiple containers running perfectly fine for months. Last week I switched ISP and use their router to connect to the internet. Since then my containers are unable to make any outbound requests. I first thought there was a problem with Docker itself ([original question asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77733463/docker-dns-127-0-0-11-cannot-resolve-anything)) but as only 1 variable changed, my ISP, my suspicion is that the problem is there. I tried calling them but they were of truly no help. Forwarding port 53 is indeed blocked inside the router but that shouldn't matter for outbound traffic, should it?

Here's a few snippets of error logs from a few of my containers (which all run Alpine Linux):

```
performing request: Get "https://acme.zerossl.com/v2/DV90": dial tcp: lookup acme.zerossl.com on 127.0.0.11:53: read udp 127.0.0.1:43815->127.0.0.11:53: i/o timeout
```

```
[✗] DNS resolution is not available
```

```
Get "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SelfhostedPro/selfhosted_templates/portainer-2.0/Template/template.json": dial tcp: lookup raw.githubusercontent.com on 8.8.4.4:53: read udp 172.17.0.2:35990->8.8.4.4:53: i/o timeout
```

```
Error trying to get announcements from Github. Connection Error
```

How do I confirm my suspicion that this is indeed router related and how would I go about solving this?

Comment: It looks like you are using `dnsmasq` for `DNS` server (for cache DNS etc..). The resolver is not able to request `8.8.4.4:53` (which is a Google Public DNS server). You got a timeout, so it is a firewall blocking issue.  You can't resolve anything from your containers.

Comment: @hidigoudi Its indeed the new router that I received. I tried completely turning off its firewall (just for testing purposes), but that did not resolve the issue. What other options are there left for me?

Comment: What is the error ? You got a timeout or something else ? - Are you able to run from the container : `host github.com` or `nslookup github.com` without error ? - You can also try to force the DNS resolver by using : `dig @8.8.4.4 github.com`

Comment: @hidigoudi Still a timeout, yes. My containers are unable to find both `dig` and `host` but `nslookup` returns the following: `;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached`. Still, even if I were to force the DNS, it wouldn't matter because the very request is blocked, is it not?

Comment: Yes you still have a firewall blocking. If you disabled the firewall, something else in the network blocks DNS requests. You should open `UDP` port `53` (you can also open `TCP` port `53` but `DNS` protocol uses `UDP` by default).

Comment: A good test would be to run `nslookup github.com 8.8.4.4` in another machine **in the same network** as your container. - If the `nslookup` can resolve the name, the issue is *probably* in your container, if it's the same behavior (a timeout), then it's *probably* a network issue.

Comment: @hidigoudi I wish I could. When I try to do so in the router, I get the following warning: `The following reserved ports cannot be forwarded because of safety reasons: (53,135,137,139,161,162)`. Would putting this one in bridge mode and using an external router allow me to bypass this restriction?

Comment: This warning is not related to your problem. It's about `port forwarding`, so the `NAT` in your internal network (when traffic **comes from** the internet). This is probably a firmware restriction from your ISP. - Your problem is located on the outgoing traffic (inside the firewall).  - Have you tried to put the default gateway (the router IP) instead of `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` for the DNS resolver inside the container ? - Normally the router itself is a `DNS resolver`.

Comment: @hidigoudi Thanks for the explanation. So not related to the ISP, gotcha. So if I understand you correctly, you want me to add the default gateway (in my case 192.168.2.1) to my container? In this case I added it to `/etc/resolv.conf` and it did change the errors, albeit slightly: `context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150583/discussion-between-hidigoudi-and-dennis-zaragosa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ISP to blame?

Yes. Your `ISP` is blocking `DNS queries` to external `DNS resolvers` like `8.8.8.8` or `8.8.4.4`. Even by disabling completely the `firewall`, you got a timeout. These blocking are either in your home router's firmware or in the ISP's router. Some ISPs intentionally block these requests to force their clients to use their **own** `DNS resolvers`.

To solve your issue, your Docker container should use the `DNS server` of his network (the router's IP address) instead of `8.8.8.8` or `8.8.4.4`. Your router is also a `DNS resolver`.

Be careful with `Docker` containers `DNS` management :

> Containers use the same DNS servers as the host by default, but you
> can override this with --dns.
>
> By default, containers inherit the DNS settings as defined in the
> /etc/resolv.conf configuration file. Containers that attach to the
> default bridge network receive a copy of this file. Containers that
> attach to a custom network use Docker's embedded DNS server. The
> embedded DNS server forwards external DNS lookups to the DNS servers
> configured on the host.

[Reference here](https://docs.docker.com/network/#dns-services)

As I know you are using `Alpine Linux` (please edit your question to add this information), please refer to [this](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Configure_Networking) page to change the network configuration on **your host machine**.

Comment: While fidgeting in docker did not get me the desired result, this did make me take a second look at my modem/router setup. Eventually I bought a third party router, but my ISP's modem in bridge mode and now everything works well again!